# Multiple Application Classes by Extension

Tags: java, android, android-manifest, android-application-class

I wanted to have multiple Application Classes just to clean up my code.

So I created 4 classes.

1.A General Class for future references:

```
public class GlobalVariables extends Application {



}
```

2. A Times Class for my time functions:

   ```
   public class SetZmanim extends GlobalVariables {
   static double latitude, longitude, elevation;
   static String locationName;
   static TimeZone timeZone;
   static GeoLocation location;
   static ComplexZmanimCalendar czc;


   public void setZmanimAPI() {
       locationName = "Queens, NY";
       latitude = 40.725058; //Lakewood, NJ
       longitude = -73.815653; //Lakewood, NJ
       elevation = 0; //optional elevation
       timeZone = TimeZone.getTimeZone("America/New_York");
       location = new GeoLocation(locationName, latitude, longitude, elevation, timeZone);
       czc = new ComplexZmanimCalendar(location);

   }
   ```

   }
3. and 4 are implemented the same way as 2 extending the original class

Here is my Manifest:

```
    <application
    android:name=".GlobalVariables"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
```

Error:
`java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.edonfreiner.siddur/com.example.edonfreiner.siddur.MainActivity}: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.example.edonfreiner.siddur.GlobalVariables cannot be cast to com.example.edonfreiner.siddur.SetStyles`

Failing part:

```
SetStyles setStyles;
setStyles = ((SetStyles) this.getApplication());
```

Comment: Well I don't agree that this cleans up your code (I'd tell a junior to redo this in a heartbeat).  And keeping dozens of statics in Application is considered a bad idea these days.  But either way, you didn't post the part of the code that's actually failing-  there's a cast problem somewhere.

Comment: Sorry, youre right. just added it. So if i need many variables in other classes, what should I do? and why does it not make my code cleaner?